# Azure VM's of sepetare ASG's with access denied are connecting through RDP

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, rdp

I'm trying to practice application security groups. Created two VM's and assosiated them to two NSG's with RDP allowed at lower priority. Then created and assigned ASG for each VM. Created rules in both NSG's to deny access between the asg's with highest priority. Verified that the access was denied between the two VM's on port 3389 in network watcher.
But, when I tried to connect to second VM through RDP from inside the first VM it is connecting (when it shouldn't connect) without any problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   I tried to test the same scenario as described by you in the question. But since, **connecting to VMs over RDP port 3389 is prohibited in my organization, so I tested the inbound connection from the other VM to the host VM and vice versa to check whether connection over RDP Port 3389 is permitted or not between these VMs**.

But the ***`connectivity was not allowed due to organization wide network security rule and not because of the high priority ASG Deny rule created in both the Network Security Groups`***. Please check the screenshots below for reference: -

Screenshot of 2nd VM: -

[image: NSG Snap]

Screenshot of 1st VM: -

[image: NSG Snap-2]

•   Thus, **connection from one VM to another through RDP Port 3389 is surely possible even after configuring the RDP access to be disallowed for the ASG assigned to both the VMs**. Because, since ***`both the VMs are deployed in the same virtual network, they can communicate with each other by default over any port`***. But please note that you are connecting to the first VM either through SSH or Bastion host because **RDP access from your local system is not possible since the ASG-Deny rule created prevents connections to Port 3389 inbound from the internet as inbound traffic from the internet is denied to all the resources by default**.

Also, as you are ***`trying to access the other VM from the first VM over RDP port 3389, you can do so as stated above because communication between two VMs in the same network is allowed by default and it is not considered an inbound connection from the internet since, public IP for both the VMs is registered as being in the same virtual network`***.

Please find the below snapshots for more clarification: -

VM1: -

[image: ASG_Deny rule]

VM2: -

[image: ASG_Deny rule-2]

Please find the below documentation link for more detailed information on the above: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-filter-network-traffic#test-traffic-filters***